# Scanner Says JAVA_HOME exists but isn't a valid Java Home

Tags: java, sonarqube, teamcity, java-home, sonarqube-scan

We have the following value for JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91

We can navigate via Windows Explorer to that location, and you can get to "\bin\java.exe".  We've also done a cd to %JAVA_HOME% to verify that resolves correctly.

However, the scanner step in TeamCity is throwing "ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there."

I've noticed that the SonarQube plug-in for TeamCity has a JDK override where you can pass the location of the java home.  Does the manual process have the same?  We cannot use the TeamCity plug-in because it is not correctly sending the unit tests results to the web app, hence our switch to the manual process.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: run as admin didn't work?

Comment: Just install a JDK and use that as your JAVA_HOME

Comment: A JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is not the JDK (Java Development Kit).

Answer (score 2):

Are these values being placed in a command line call? Depending on the situation spaces in path names can cause problems with tools. If you can, try installing Java to a folder that does not have spaces. As an alternative you could also use the Windows short name in JAVA_HOME for "Program Files". This is usually "PROGRA~1".

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, but I am using the TFS 2018 and build server, both builder server and the SonarQube server have JDK 11, BUT still i am facing the issue?